# Get integer value from edittext And Access value on Button

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, integer

I want to get int Value from Edittext and then access that value On Button. But When I Access On Button It Show Error Remove "Final" modifier of "val". When I remove it then on button listener `mViewPager.setCurrentItem(val);` Show error That `Change modifier of 'val'to Final`.
Here Is my Code

```
     bt_Goto =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_goto);

     bt_next =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
     bt_Prev =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_prev);

     ed_text =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

     final int val=-1;
     if(ed_text.getText().toString().length() > 0){
     val = Integer.parseInt( ed_text.getText().toString() );
     }
    // String str = ed_text.getText().toString().trim();


     mViewPager = (ExtendedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

     mViewPager.setAdapter(new TouchImageAdapter());
     mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

        bt_Goto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(val);
            }
        });
```

**Full Code:**

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppAd;
import com.startapp.android.publish.StartAppSDK;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button bt_next,bt_Prev,bt_Goto;
EditText ed_text;
ImageView iv;
ExtendedViewPager mViewPager;
AdView adView;

int val=-1;

private StartAppAd startAppAd = new StartAppAd(this);
private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-3785804349839269/3077204438";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

StartAppSDK.init(this, "101607288", "201235812", true);

        startAppAd.showAd(); // show the ad
        startAppAd.loadAd(); // load the next ad

         AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
         AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
         adView.loadAd(adRequest);


         // Create an ad.
         adView = new AdView(this);
         adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
         adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID);

         bt_Goto =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_goto);
         bt_next =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_next);
         bt_Prev =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_prev);

         ed_text =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);


         if(ed_text.getText().toString().length() > 0){
         val = Integer.parseInt( ed_text.getText().toString() );
         }
        // String str = ed_text.getText().toString().trim();


         mViewPager = (ExtendedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

         mViewPager.setAdapter(new TouchImageAdapter());
         mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);

            bt_Goto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(val);
                }
            });

        }

        static class TouchImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

            private static int[] images = 
                {R.raw.a0002,R.raw.a0003,R.raw.a0004,R.raw.a0005,R.raw.a0006,R.raw.a0007,R.raw.a0008,R.raw.a0009,R.raw.a0010,
                R.raw.a0011,R.raw.a0012,R.raw.a0013,R.raw.a0014,R.raw.a0015,R.raw.a0016,R.raw.a0017,R.raw.a0018,R.raw.a0019,R.raw.a0020,
                R.raw.a0021,R.raw.a0022,R.raw.a0023,R.raw.a0024,R.raw.a0025,R.raw.a0026,R.raw.a0027,R.raw.a0028,R.raw.a0029,R.raw.a0030,
                R.raw.a0031,R.raw.a0032,R.raw.a0033,R.raw.a0034,R.raw.a0035,R.raw.a0036,R.raw.a0037,R.raw.a0038,R.raw.a0039,R.raw.a0040,
                R.raw.a0041,R.raw.a0042,R.raw.a0043,R.raw.a0044,R.raw.a0045,R.raw.a0046,R.raw.a0047,R.raw.a0048,R.raw.a0049,R.raw.a0050,
                R.raw.a0051,R.raw.a0052,R.raw.a0053,R.raw.a0054,R.raw.a0055,R.raw.a0056,R.raw.a0057,R.raw.a0058,R.raw.a0059,R.raw.a0060,
                R.raw.a0061,R.raw.a0062,R.raw.a0063,R.raw.a0064,R.raw.a0065,R.raw.a0066,R.raw.a0067,R.raw.a0068,R.raw.a0069,R.raw.a0070,
                R.raw.a0071,R.raw.a0072,R.raw.a0073,R.raw.a0074,R.raw.a0075,R.raw.a0076,R.raw.a0077,R.raw.a0078,R.raw.a0079,R.raw.a0080,
                R.raw.a0081,R.raw.a0082,R.raw.a0083,R.raw.a0084,R.raw.a0085,R.raw.a0086,R.raw.a0087,R.raw.a0088,R.raw.a0089,R.raw.a0090,
                R.raw.a0091,R.raw.a0092,R.raw.a0093,R.raw.a0094,R.raw.a0095,R.raw.a0096,R.raw.a0097,R.raw.a0098,R.raw.a0099,R.raw.a0100,

                R.raw.a0101,R.raw.a0102,R.raw.a0103,R.raw.a0104,R.raw.a0105,R.raw.a0106,R.raw.a0107,R.raw.a0108,R.raw.a0109,R.raw.a0110,
                R.raw.a0111,R.raw.a0112,R.raw.a0113,R.raw.a0114,R.raw.a0115,R.raw.a0116,R.raw.a0117,R.raw.a0118,R.raw.a0119,R.raw.a0120,
                R.raw.a0121,R.raw.a0122,R.raw.a0123,R.raw.a0124,R.raw.a0125,R.raw.a0126,R.raw.a0127,R.raw.a0128,R.raw.a0129,R.raw.a0130,
                R.raw.a0131,R.raw.a0132,R.raw.a0133,R.raw.a0134,R.raw.a0135,R.raw.a0136,R.raw.a0137,R.raw.a0138,R.raw.a0139,R.raw.a0140,
                R.raw.a0141,R.raw.a0142,R.raw.a0143,R.raw.a0144,R.raw.a0145,R.raw.a0146,R.raw.a0147,R.raw.a0148,R.raw.a0149,R.raw.a0150,
                R.raw.a0151,R.raw.a0152,R.raw.a0153,R.raw.a0154,R.raw.a0155,R.raw.a0156,R.raw.a0157,R.raw.a0158,R.raw.a0159,R.raw.a0160,
                R.raw.a0161,R.raw.a0162,R.raw.a0163,R.raw.a0164,R.raw.a0165,R.raw.a0166,R.raw.a0167,R.raw.a0168,R.raw.a0169,R.raw.a0170,
                R.raw.a0171,R.raw.a0172,R.raw.a0173,R.raw.a0174,R.raw.a0175,R.raw.a0176,R.raw.a0177,R.raw.a0178,R.raw.a0179,R.raw.a0180,
                R.raw.a0181,R.raw.a0182,R.raw.a0183,R.raw.a0184,R.raw.a0185,R.raw.a0186,R.raw.a0187,R.raw.a0188,R.raw.a0189,R.raw.a0190,
                R.raw.a0191,R.raw.a0192,R.raw.a0193,R.raw.a0194,R.raw.a0195,R.raw.a0196,R.raw.a0197,R.raw.a0198,R.raw.a0199,R.raw.a0200,

                R.raw.a0201,R.raw.a0202,R.raw.a0203,R.raw.a0204,R.raw.a0205,R.raw.a0206,R.raw.a0207,R.raw.a0208,R.raw.a0209,R.raw.a0210,
                R.raw.a0211,R.raw.a0212,R.raw.a0213,R.raw.a0214,R.raw.a0215,R.raw.a0216,R.raw.a0217,R.raw.a0218,R.raw.a0219,R.raw.a0220,
                R.raw.a0221,R.raw.a0222,R.raw.a0223,R.raw.a0224,R.raw.a0225,R.raw.a0226,R.raw.a0227,R.raw.a0228,R.raw.a0229,R.raw.a0230,
                R.raw.a0231,R.raw.a0232,R.raw.a0233,R.raw.a0234,R.raw.a0235,R.raw.a0236,R.raw.a0237,R.raw.a0238,R.raw.a0239,R.raw.a0240,
                R.raw.a0241,R.raw.a0242,R.raw.a0343,R.raw.a0344,R.raw.a0245,R.raw.a0246,R.raw.a0347,R.raw.a0248,R.raw.a0249,R.raw.a0250,
                R.raw.a0251,R.raw.a0252,R.raw.a0253,R.raw.a0254,R.raw.a0255,R.raw.a0256,R.raw.a0257,R.raw.a0258,R.raw.a0259,R.raw.a0260,
                R.raw.a0261,R.raw.a0262,R.raw.a0263,R.raw.a0264,R.raw.a0265,R.raw.a0266,R.raw.a0267,R.raw.a0268,R.raw.a0269,R.raw.a0270,
                R.raw.a0271,R.raw.a0272,R.raw.a0273,R.raw.a0274,R.raw.a0275,R.raw.a0276,R.raw.a0277,R.raw.a0278,R.raw.a0279,R.raw.a0280,
                R.raw.a0281,R.raw.a0282,R.raw.a0283,R.raw.a0284,R.raw.a0285,R.raw.a0286,R.raw.a0287,R.raw.a0288,R.raw.a0289,R.raw.a0290,
                R.raw.a0291,R.raw.a0292,R.raw.a0293,R.raw.a0294,R.raw.a0295,R.raw.a0296,R.raw.a0297,R.raw.a0298,R.raw.a0299,R.raw.a0300,

                R.raw.a0301,R.raw.a0302,R.raw.a0303,R.raw.a0304,R.raw.a0305,R.raw.a0306,R.raw.a0307,R.raw.a0308,R.raw.a0309,R.raw.a0310,
                R.raw.a0311,R.raw.a0312,R.raw.a0313,R.raw.a0314,R.raw.a0315,R.raw.a0316,R.raw.a0317,R.raw.a0318,R.raw.a0319,R.raw.a0320,
                R.raw.a0321,R.raw.a0322,R.raw.a0323,R.raw.a0324,R.raw.a0325,R.raw.a0326,R.raw.a0327,R.raw.a0328,R.raw.a0329,R.raw.a0330,
                R.raw.a0331,R.raw.a0332,R.raw.a0333,R.raw.a0334,R.raw.a0335,R.raw.a0336,R.raw.a0337,R.raw.a0338,R.raw.a0339,R.raw.a0340,
                R.raw.a0341,R.raw.a0342,R.raw.a0343,R.raw.a0344,R.raw.a0345,R.raw.a0346,R.raw.a0347,R.raw.a0348,R.raw.a0349,R.raw.a0350,
                R.raw.a0351,R.raw.a0352,R.raw.a0353,R.raw.a0354,R.raw.a0355,R.raw.a0356,R.raw.a0357,R.raw.a0358,R.raw.a0359,R.raw.a0360,
                R.raw.a0361,R.raw.a0362,R.raw.a0363,R.raw.a0364};

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return images.length;
            }


            @Override
            public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                TouchImageView img = new TouchImageView(container.getContext());
                img.setImageResource(images[position]);
                container.addView(img, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                return img;


            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                container.removeView((View) object);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }


    }



}
```

Comment: Make "val"
 as global variable and remove final then use it

Comment: I did it but Then no Action occur when pressing button

Comment: Thanks For The Reply My question was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the ed_text  and mViewPager in your onCreate like this

```
 final EditText ed_text =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 final ExtendedViewPager mViewPager = (ExtendedViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
```

and now you can access the ed_text value in the bt_Goto click listener like this

```
 bt_Goto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(ed_text.getText().toString().length() > 0){
                    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(Integer.parseInt( ed_text.getText().toString()));
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank dude It Works Like Charm!!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `final` keyword from your `int`

```
final int val=-1;
```

^^^^ remove that

Besides that, declare it as a class field so you can access it in the listener scope.

Comment: how can i declare please write in my code and post in cmnt thanks

Answer (score 0):

Declare your int val variable at class level
And when it come to method initialise it with -1.

Hope fully it ll work.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using temp variable.

```
int value_temp = -1;
 if(ed_text.getText().toString().length() > 0){
     value_temp = Integer.parseInt( ed_text.getText().toString() );
 }
 final int value = value_temp;

 bt_Goto.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(value);
            }
});
```